# write join query in php yii using CDBcriteria

Tags: php, yii

Hi am quite new to php  yii i have following query

```
select d.* from customer_service_provider csp inner join (select id_customers from customer_devices cd where id_devices=2) as c on csp.id_customers=c.id_customers inner join user_devices ud on ud.id_users = csp.id_users inner join devices d on d.id = ud.id_devices
```

how can i write in to php yii using CDBcriteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't get 'devices' (d.*) FROM 'customer_service_provider' with $criteria and CActiveDataProvider.

Because CActiveDataProvider need a model to convert the query result in a list of objects of that model, but in this case you would have to pass the model 'customer_service_provider' class.

sorry for my english..

Comment: `CDbCriteria` supports joins just fine. You can construct a `CActiveDataProvider` from a model finder whose criteria has joins: `$finder = new CSP(); $finder->dbCriteria->mergeWith(array('join' => 'foo')); new CActiveDataProvider($finder);`

Comment: I am not saying CDbCriteria haven't joins, say that you can't pass to the CActiveDataProvider a model waiting to pick up another.